# Taking Database Backups with partially data from SQL Server tables

Tags: database, azure-sql-database, backup, restore

Could someone please help to achieve is this, my requirement is as follows:

I have a database and it is in Azure, we have scheduled backups (point-in-time restore options available), and now I want to restore one of the dated database backup to my local. But I don't require all the data from all the tables,
I only need some portion of the data from every table,

Say for example I have 2 tables, and the data available in each table 1000 and 2000 records respectively and are related too, now I wanted to take only 100 and 200 records which are related, from backup and restore option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The backups only support restore all the data during point time. We can not specify the portion of the data from every table to restore.

Just for now, your request can not be achieved.

Comment: Thank you Leon!!, i believe that even in SQL server Also it wont be possible right, if not please guide me on that,

Comment: Hi @user3733012, yes, you're right,. It's also impossible in SQL Server.If my answer is helpful for you, hope you can accept it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.). This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.